# How to control work folder for Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Normally, if you are using a self-hosted Azure agent, it automatically selects target folders for you (I assume based on pipeline name), underneath the work folder... so for example:

```
/home/xxxxx/azure/_work/2/t/
```

Is there a way that I can control this choice from a YAML pipeline? My use case is that I have a very large repo, and several different pipelines that all check it out. I only have one agent running on the machine, so my preference is that *all* of the pipelines I run on this agent check out into the same folder (like `/home/xxxxx/azure/_work/MyProject`), ensuring that there will only be one checkout of this large repo.

Comment: Have you considered doing shallow checkouts to reduce the cloned repo size?

Comment: @DanielMann This is a good idea, I might use in some other contexts.  My preference in this case is still to use one folder if I can, because there are a bunch of other dependencies and cacheable assets that can be reused if I don't check out fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid syncing sources at all in the pipeline by setting `checkout: none`:

```
steps:
- checkout: none
```

Then add a command line or script task to clone the repo manually via git commands.

Comment: Thanks Cece - I don't know if that helps.  I can clone the repo manually, but the value of `pwd` will still potentially one of many random folders (`1/s`, `2/t`, etc.).  I guess I could add a script step that does `mkdir -p ../../myWorkFolder && cd ../../myWorkFolder`, but my concern is that this will break any tasks like collect coverage & publish artifacts that assume my files are in a normal work folder.

Comment: You could set source folder for these tasks.

Comment: OK -- so one option is to just work "outside the _work folder", in a place of my choosing, and just do things manually. Makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

We've recently been testing linking the source folder and it has been working pretty well, so that is possibly an easier answer than the accepted one.

That is, you can create a specific folder (let's say `~/projects/Acme` or `C:\projects\acme`), and then in your Azure pipeline `steps` *before checkout* you delete the `s` folder and link it to the target project folder.

```
# In PowerShell (Windows)
New-Item -Type Junction -Path s -Target C:\projects\acme

# In Bash (Linux/MacOS)
ln -s ~/projects/acme s
```

The advantage to this approach is that you don't have to attempt to override the working folder for dozens of builtin tasks scattered throughout your pipelines and template files; it's a bit of setup at the top of the pipeline and then the rest of the tasks can operate as normal.